# Most elegant way to select rows by a string value

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a more elegant way to write this code:

```
df['exchange'] = frame.loc[frame['Description'].str.lower().str.contains("on wallet exchange")]
```

The .str twice seems ugly.

When I iterate over the entire dataframe row by row, I can use:

```
if "on wallet exchange" in row['Description'].casefold():
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `case=False` , also add `na=False` to be safe so if the series contains either numerics(@ jezrael-Thank you ) or NaN , this will be evaluated as False

```
frame.loc[frame['Description'].str.contains("on wallet exchange",case=False,na=False)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **`case=False`** parameter for the [**`str.contains(..)`** method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
frame.loc[frame['Description'].str.contains('on wallet exchange', case=False)]
```

Note that `.casefold()` and `.lower()` are *not* equivalent, these have some special cultural rules, for example the [*eszett ß* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eszet) maps on `'ss'`, since it is considered to be equivalent with `'SS'`. Pandas has a [**`str.casefold(..)`** method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.casefold.html) to map on case-invariant folds of the original string.

Answer (score 2):

Or use:

```
frame[frame['Description'].str.contains('(?i)on wallet exchange')]
```